# Stopping marquee with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

Is there any way I can stop `marquee` with `CSS` ? I cannot use `javascript` for security reasons.

How can I do this with css ?

EDIT :  I want to stop it on mouse hover and start it otherwise.

Comment: Stop in which sense? Do you mean preventing `marquee` from causing the effect at all, or to stop at some moment or after some repetitions?

Comment: Avoid the marquee tag is being depecated.

Comment: @M1K1O What should i use then ?

Comment: @saplingPro regular tag like `div` with `CSS` marquee styles. http://www.html-5.com/css/css-styles/css-style-properties/marquee-style.html

Answer (score 0):

```
marquee:hover
{
  -moz-binding: none;
}
```

Try this. But the purpose of -moz-binding is different. But it works.

[Refer this for Webkit](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/scrolling-text-with-webkit-marquee/) Reference: SO

Comment: `-moz` prefixes are Mozilla Firefox specific

Comment: For some reason, `moz-binding: none` works when set on `marquee` but not when set on `marquee:hover`.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<p class="microsoft marquee"><span>Windows 8 and ...</span></p>
```

CSS

```
.marquee {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;  /* show the marquee just outside the paragraph */
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

Comment: where is the `marquee` class ?

Comment: This does not answer the question about stopping `marquee` but suggests replacing `marquee` by another element and styling. The code fails badly in Chrome: the text is not shown at all. (It also fails badly in old browser versions that do not support CSS animation but do support the setting the element initially off-screen.)